# MySQL: joining tables with multi results rows to one row

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables:

```
secu_content
| id  | created    | modified   |
| 910 | 26/12/1982 | 28/12/1984 |
| 911 | 24/12/1982 | 25/12/1984 |

secu_data
| element_id | field_id | data       |
|          1 |        1 | 25/12/1984 |
|          2 |        1 | 26/12/1984 |
|          3 |        1 | 27/12/1984 |
|          4 |        1 | 25/12/1984 |
|          4 |        2 | google.com |

secu_elements
| id | item_id |
|  1 |     891 |
|  2 |     711 |
|  3 |     204 |
|  4 |     911 |

secu_fields
| id | type  |
|  1 | date  |
|  2 | input |
```

Table secu_content, contains many articles, where the id is the article id.
The other 3 tables gives additional information and I want to join them.

I want to get results that includes all secu_content rows and all the columns + calc_date + calc_link

calc_date <- the data column from secu_data where field_id=1 (see secu_fields)

calc_link <- the data column from secu_data where field_id=2 (see secu_fields)

The problem is that I get 2 rows where secu_content id=911 (one row with the correct calc_date and second row with the correct calc_link), and I need one row with both.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.created
     , a.modified
     , fe.item_id AS calc_date_item_id
     , fd.data AS calc_date
     , CASE WHEN fd.data IS NOT NULL AND ff.type = "date" THEN fd.data 
            WHEN a.modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.modified 
       END as calc_date
     , CASE WHEN fd.data IS NOT NULL AND ff.type = "input" THEN fd.data 
       END as calc_link 
  FROM secu_content AS a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN secu_fieldsandfilters_elements AS fe 
    ON fe.item_id = a.id 
   AND fe.content_type_id=1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN secu_fieldsandfilters_data AS fd 
    ON fd.element_id = fe.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN secu_fieldsandfilters_fields as ff 
    ON ff.id = fd.field_id 
 ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

Thanks in advance

Israel

Comment: Dates and times adhere to a specific format in SQL. This is not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast and dirty solution is to use second join to secu_data like that (simplified, add logic you need)

```
SELECT id, d1.data as `calc_date`, d2.data as `calc_link`
FROM secu_content 
LEFT JOIN secu_data d1 ON secu_content.id = d1.element_id AND field_id = 1
LEFT JOIN secu_data d2 ON secu_content.id = d2.element_id AND field_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks,
This solved my problem in case there are 2 fields, but in the future when I will have more fields (for example 50), it will not be efficient.